# Responsive web application with floating buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am developing an infographic that has a couple of floating buttons above an image. So far, no problem, I make all of them absolute positioned and everything should work.

However, it is very important that the infographic scales to different window sizes. I managed to get the images scaling perfectly, however, the absolute positioned buttons get misplaced.

Is there a standard "Responsive Web Design way" of solving this problem? Right now, the only thing I can think of is getting how much the image shrinked and applying this factor to the position and sizes of all the floating buttons using Javascript.

EDIT: Posting some code.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="main">

    <img src="imgs/01_negimpacto.gif"></img>

    <div class="bt bt-pag" id="pag02"></div>
    <div class="bt bt-pag" id="pag03"></div>
    <div class="bt bt-pag" id="pag04"></div>
    <div class="bt bt-pag" id="pag05"></div>
    <div class="bt bt-pag" id="pag06"></div>

    <img id="img-pag02" class="pag" src="imgs/01_pag02.png"></img>
    <img id="img-pag03" class="pag" src="imgs/01_pag03.png"></img>
    <img id="img-pag04" class="pag" src="imgs/01_pag04.png"></img>
    <img id="img-pag05" class="pag" src="imgs/01_pag05.png"></img>            
    <img id="img-pag06" class="pag" src="imgs/01_pag06.png"></img>

    <div class="bt" id="xis"></div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main img {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.pag {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.bt {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#xis {
    position:absolute;
    left:310px;
    top:0px;
    width:40px;
    height:37px;
}

#pag02 {
    position:absolute;
    left:237px;
    top:106px;
    width:31px;
    height:31px;
}

#pag03 {
    position:absolute;
    left:12px;
    top:187px;
    width:31px;
    height:32px;
}

#pag04 {
    position:absolute;
    left:12px;
    top:267px;
    width:31px;
    height:32px;
}

#pag05 {
    position:absolute;
    left:12px;
    top:337px;
    width:31px;
    height:32px;
}

#pag06 {
    position:absolute;
    left:12px;
    top:422px;
    width:31px;
    height:32px;
}
```

The .bt-pag divs are the buttons that toggle the visibility of their img counterparts. #xis is a button that just hides any visible image. Here is the javascript that I am currently using to resize and reposition everything:

```
if($(window).width() < maxWidth)
{
    var prop = $(window).width() / maxWidth;

    $(".bt").each(function(i) {
        $(this).css("top", $(this).position().top * prop);
        $(this).css("left", $(this).position().left * prop);
        $(this).css("width", $(this).width() * prop);
        $(this).css("height", $(this).height() * prop);
    });
}
```

maxWidth is the background image maximum size (350px).

Comment: Well the "standard" way is media queries.

Comment: 1) Why do you use `div` for buttons? Instead of `<input type='button'>`? 2) `img` don't need closing tags. 3) Is a given button related to one and only one `img`?

Comment: 1) Preference. The buttons must be invisible, and <input type='button'> comes with default styling. 2) Ok, I'll remove the closing tags then. 3) Yes. Sorry, but I can't see how these questions are related with my specific question.

Comment: Well, your question is about responsive design, which I've said is typically handled by media queries, certainly as a foundation. I ask about divs instead of buttons for more background (divs are block level elements and have default styling too), re: one button per img, I was going to suggest a containment structure. `<div with img bg><div button></div></div>` This would allow for relative positioning. Since you don't say exactly how the buttons are misplaced it just leaves us guessing at things. I mean `$(window).width() / maxWidth` is an x ratio, so i assume the `img` is perfectly square

Comment: given you then offset the top (y axis) `$(this).css("top", $(this).position().top * prop);` by the same ratio?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the image will only be scaled on its width. The resulting height is proportional. The code I posted already solves my problem, but I don't feel that it is the right thing to do. Is it a good solution?